# create object in object JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi i have object which has container element and same subElement:

```
var Obj = function(){
    this.container = $('.obj');
    this.subObjs = container.find('.subObj'); 
}
```

In this Obj i want create another Object(ObjHandler) who ad handlerOn click for each sub object.

```
 var Obj = function(){
    this.container = $('.obj');
    this.subObjs = container.find('.subObj'); 

    this.init = function() {
       this.subObjs.each(function(i,el){
         el = new this.ObjHandler(el)
      });
    }

    this.ObjHandler = function(element) {
       this.el = element;
       this.element.on('click',function(){
           console.log('click');
      });
   }

}
```

I know i cam make it simple way like `this.subObjs.on('click', function(){})`
but i this is only simplification.

here is on [codepen.io](http://codepen.io/Messa/pen/XKpXQZ?editors=0011)

Is it good idea and why its no works?

Comment: Do you have a question? Is there a problem with your code?

Comment: i think you have a problem accessing the `ObjHandler(el)` within `subObjs.each`. To overcome that issue; just create `var self = this;` at first line in `this.init() {` function and then use that variable inside `.each(` like `el = new self.ObjHandler(el)`.

Comment: So it is good idea? i try it but it doesnt work can you show me how to do it?  http://codepen.io/Messa/pen/XKpXQZ?editors=0011

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `this.element` is not defined use either `this.el` or `element`
- `element` is an instance of the native JS `Element`. Wrap it with `$()` to get a jQuery object that defines the `on` function
- You never create an instance of `Obj` or call `init`

[fixed pen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZOLQda)

Comment: Thanks you, now i see it and learn something new i just have a idea but don know ho to do it right.